# In what issue did Magneto trap Banshee in a metal suit?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, x-men, episode-identification, magneto

I have been doing research for an X-Men fan-fiction story, and recently found a picture online, depicting Banshee trapped in a metal suit, along with 2 more pictures, one which shows Magneto using dust particles to do this and the other with Cyclops shattering the metal with his optic blast. I am having a hard time finding the pictures again, and no matter where I look, I can't for the life of me, find what issue this is. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This occurs in the [Uncanny X-Men #104](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/the-x-men-104-the-gentlemans-name-is-magneto/4000-17371/) story "***The Gentleman's Name Is Magneto***" from 1977. It was re-released in the 1987 retrospective [Classic X-Men 12](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/classic-x-men-12-the-gentlemans-name-is-magneto-a-/4000-47400/)

**Fights Banshee**
[image]

**Encases him in metal dust**
[image]

**Cyclops frees him**
[image]

Comment: @Valorum Ah, thanks for editing it in.

Comment: I was just in the process of writing it up when I spotted your answer. I've taken the liberty of adding in some links as well.